# python for save each list into some output file and store output file in another directory

Tags: python, file-io, io

i already have this code

```
#!usr.bin/env python
with open('honeyd.txt', 'r') as infile:
     for index, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
         with open('TA_rule_{}.rule'format(index), 'w') as outfile:
              outfile.write('alert {} {} -> {} {}\n'.format(*line.split()))
```

this code split all lines and save into some output file. this script I put in directory /etc/snort.

the output file is store in directory /etc/snort

my goal is to store the output file in /etc/snort/rules

anyone can help with it?

Comment: Prepend "rules/" to the filename for `outfile` (in the second call to `open`)?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a programming course or tutorial instead of asking StackOverflow to  write your code for you one line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...
with `open('DiskName:\\Path\\etc\\snort\\rules\\fileName.txt', 'w')` as outfile:
...